# Check if quotes and parentheses are balanced

Tags: javascript, algorithm

There are multiple solutions to how to check if parentheses are balanced, but I haven't found a single one that would be checking both for balanced quotes and parentheses.

I have been unsuccessfully trying to adapt this solution [(codereview - balanced parentheses)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/45991/balanced-parentheses) to be able to check if the quotes and parentheses are balanced.

For example this should be unbalanced `("back-to-school)"`

Original code:

```
function parenthesesAreBalanced(string) {
  var parentheses = "[]{}()",
    stack = [],
    i, character, bracePosition;

  for(i = 0; character = string[i]; i++) {
    bracePosition = parentheses.indexOf(character);

    if(bracePosition === -1) {
      continue;
    }

    if(bracePosition % 2 === 0) {
      stack.push(bracePosition + 1); // push next expected brace position
    } else {
      if(stack.length === 0 || stack.pop() !== bracePosition) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }

  return stack.length === 0;
}
```

My code - mostly similar - but added an unbalanced quotes check.

```
function areQuotesAndParenthesesBalanced(s: string): boolean {
  const parens = '[]{}()',
      parensStack = [];
  let index, char, numOfQuotes = 0;

  for (index = 0; char = s[index++];){
      const bracePosition = parens.indexOf(char);
      let braceType;

    if (bracePosition === -1 && char !== '"')
        continue;

    braceType = bracePosition % 2 ? 'closed' : 'open';

    //check for double quotes mixed with parentheses
    if(char === '"'){
        const lastInStack = parensStack[parensStack.length - 1];

        numOfQuotes++;

        if(lastInStack === '"'){
            numOfQuotes--;
            parensStack.pop();
        }else if(numOfQuotes > 0 && lastInStack !== '"'){
            return false;
        }else{
            parensStack.push('"');
        }
    }

    if (braceType === 'closed') {
        if (!parensStack.length || parens.indexOf(parensStack.pop()) != bracePosition - 1)
            return false;
    } else {
        parensStack.push(char);
    }
}

//If anything is left on the stack <- not balanced
return !parensStack.length;
}
```

It is quite tricky for me to determine what's the best approach. With parentheses, you always know when one is open or closed, with quotes, not so much.

Comment: The solution should be the exact same no matter what symbol you're using, just also checks for quotes in the same way you would check for brackets

Comment: @Mitchel0022 - I have already tried that and it doesn't work due to how the original solution checks for open closed brackets - you can't discern whether the quote is opening or closing using the same logic.

Comment: Your specification is incomplete. Do you want to check balance of parentheses inside quoted strings? Is `("])}")` a valid string?

Comment: Just change `var parentheses = "[]{}()"` to `var parentheses = "[]{}()\"\""`, same logic

Comment: @Mitchel0022 - that was the first thing I tried - I already told you it ain't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This performs a check for `push()` or `pop()` of `"` in 2 ways.

- If stack is empty or last character in stack does not equal `"`, then insert this `"` into stack.
- If stack is not empty and last character in stack is equal to `"`, then `pop()` the `"` in stack itself. This is done because I do a form of greedy matching here since a `"` for already stack `"` means expression inside `"..."` was evaluated. So, we are safe to match these 2 `"` and proceed with the next.

Works well, but let me know if it fails for any case.

```js
function areQuotesAndParenthesesBalanced(s){
 var pairs = {
  '}':'{',
  ']':'[',
  ')':'(',
 };

 var stack = [];

 for(var i = 0;i < s.length;++i){
  switch(s.charAt(i)){
   case '[': case '{':case '(':
    stack.push(s.charAt(i));
   break;
   case ']': case '}':case ')':
    if(isStackEmpty(stack) || peek(stack) !== pairs[s.charAt(i)]) return false;
    stack.pop();
   break;
   case '"':
    if(isStackEmpty(stack) || peek(stack) !== s.charAt(i)){
     stack.push(s.charAt(i));
    }else{
     stack.pop();
    }
  }
 }

 return isStackEmpty(stack);
}

function isStackEmpty(s){
 return s.length === 0;
}

function peek(s){
 return s[s.length-1];
}


var tests = {
    '("back-to-school")':true,
    '"(back-to-school)"':true,
    '("back-to-school)"':false,
    '("back-to-school)':false,
    '"["["["[]"]"]"]"':true,
    '"["]""':false,
    '"[]"""':true,
    '""""':true,
    '""':true,
    '"':false,
    '""[("")]""':true,
    '""[("")]':true,
    '"["["["[]"]"[""]]"]':false,
    '"[]"[({})]""':true,
    '"[{}"]':false
   };

for(var each_test in tests){
 var res = areQuotesAndParenthesesBalanced(each_test);
 console.log(each_test + " --> " + (res === tests[each_test] ? "ok" : "not ok") + " , expected : " + tests[each_test]);
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
("back-to-school") --> ok , expected : true
"(back-to-school)" --> ok , expected : true
("back-to-school)" --> ok , expected : false
("back-to-school) --> ok , expected : false
"["["["[]"]"]"]" --> ok , expected : true
"["]"" --> ok , expected : false
"[]""" --> ok , expected : true
"""" --> ok , expected : true
"" --> ok , expected : true
" --> ok , expected : false
""[("")]"" --> ok , expected : true
""[("")] --> ok , expected : true
"["["["[]"]"[""]]"] --> ok , expected : false
"[]"[({})]"" --> ok , expected : true
"[{}"] --> ok , expected : false
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution - I ran few tests with my inputs and haven't seen any issues.

Comment: Marked you answer as the approved one, cause it doesn't fail on this phrase `(ele AND car) OR ("ele car)")`

Comment: @codeepic Thanks :) Glad to give you an accurate answer :)

Answer (score 3):

```js
function tokensAreBalanced(string) {
  var asymmetricTokens = "[]{}()",
    symmetricTokens = '"',
    stack = [],
    i, character, tokenPosition;

  for(i = 0; character = string[i]; i++) {
    tokenPosition = asymmetricTokens.indexOf(character);

    if(tokenPosition >= 0) {
      if(tokenPosition % 2 === 0) {
        stack.push(asymmetricTokens[tokenPosition + 1]); // push next expected token
      } else if(stack.length === 0 || stack.pop() !== character) {
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      if(symmetricTokens.includes(character)) {
        if(stack.length > 0 && stack[stack.length - 1] === character) {
          stack.pop();
        } else {
          stack.push(character);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return stack.length === 0;
}


console.log('("back-to-school)"', tokensAreBalanced('("back-to-school)"'));

console.log('("back-to-school)', tokensAreBalanced('("back-to-school)'));

console.log('("back-to-school")', tokensAreBalanced('("back-to-school")'));

console.log('(ele AND car) OR ("ele car)")', tokensAreBalanced('(ele AND car) OR ("ele car)")'));
```

Comment: I like your solution - it took me a while to understand the logic with the continues and the fact that you store braceIndexes in the stack instead of actual parentheses. And you decided not to store quotes in the stack at all - opting for a boolean flag. Clever. How did you arrive to that solution? It really annoys me that I couldn't sort it in my head to come up with an algorithm for checking both the parens and the quotes.

Comment: @codeepic I think many accurate solutions are possible since this depends on how we interpret the expression. Let's take `""[("")]""` for example. First approach, we can read this as `""`,`[("")]`,`""`. Second approach is we can interpret this as `"`  `"[("")]"`  `"`.So, when we treat an `"` as start or end can vary and still be correct.

Comment: @codeepic - I didn't have to do much, you're "original solution" does most of the hard work and I just added the required logic to handle quotes. The idea is simple - a quote character either opens or closes (enters / leaves) a quoted section, so maintain a boolean flag to indicate that. Within a quoted section, anything else can be ignored - like a string. In the end we need to verify there's no open quote section.

Comment: Hi @Amit - unfortunately this `(ele AND car) OR ("ele car)")` combination will return true.

Comment: @codeepic - why is that unfortunate? That's the correct result

Comment: Well, no, cause the last quote and `)` are unbalanced.

Comment: I assumed you wanted quotes to be used as "stringification", as in a programming language. I now understand that's not what you meant so my answer needs you be changed

Comment: @Amit - don't sweat it much - I already have a working solution from vivek_23. Your solution was quite good, but our customers use a lot of weird combinations of boolean searches - I wouldn't be surprised if someone manages to get past the validation with an invalid boolean query again in the coming weeks (this time at least not caused by quotes and parens mismatch).

Answer (score 2):

You could try putting an ordered tuple on the stack and checking based off of that.

```
[(,"],
[",)],
[(,"],
[",)]

== ("")("") example of a balanced stack.

[",(],
[",(],
[),"],
[),"]

== "("()")" another balanced stack


[(,"],
[),"]

== (")" trivial unbalanced stack

[(,)] <- trivial item, can ignore in implementation
[","] <- trivial item, can ignore in implementation

[",(],
[),(],
[),"]

== "()()" balanced stack
```

I'm too tired to actually implement this, but hopefully it gave you some ideas and illustrative examples, I'll revisit it after I get some sleep.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest simplifying the input by removing all quoted substrings. Quotes behave differently because parentheses inside quotes are not treated specially, but as normal characters. By first removing each quoted part, this "problem" is resolved from the start. Also irrelevant characters (that are not parentheses nor quotes) can be removed as well. That way we are only left with a string that has parentheses and possibly a single occurrence of a quote. The latter would immediately make the input invalid.

Here is code similar to @nice_dev's answer, with that manipulation implemented and with `pairs` inversed; it also deals with apostrophe as alternative delimiter:

```js
function areQuotesAndParenthesesBalanced(s) {
    const pairs = {
        '{':'}',
        '[':']',
        '(':')',
    };

    const stack = [""]; // Dummy
    for (const token of s.replace(/"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^"'{}()[\]]+/g, "")) {
        if (token in pairs) {
            stack.push(pairs[token]);
        } else {
            if (stack.at(-1) !== token) return false;
            stack.pop();
        }
    }
    return stack.length == 1; // Empty
}

// Same tests as in the answer of @nice_dev:
const tests = {
    '("back-to-school")': true,
    '"(back-to-school)"': true,
    '("back-to-school)"': false,
    '("back-to-school)': false,
    '"["["["[]"]"]"]"': true,
    '"["]""': false,
    '"[]"""': true,
    '""""': true,
    '""': true,
    '"': false,
    '""[("")]""': true,
    '""[("")]': true,
    '"["["["[]"]"[""]]"]': false,
    '"[]"[({})]""': true,
    '"[{}"]': false
};

for (const each_test in tests){
    const res = areQuotesAndParenthesesBalanced(each_test);
    console.log(`${each_test} --> ${res === tests[each_test] ? "ok" : "not ok"}, expected: ${tests[each_test]}`);
}
```

Comment: This seems to accept `'Back "to 'school"'"`, which is pretty badly misnested.

Comment: I would consider that correctly nested: the single quoted part is `'Back "to  '`, the doubly quoted part is `"'"`.

Comment: I guess it depends on one's interpretation.  But a single `"` seems problematic to me.  A single `'` is less of an issue, as an apostrophe serves multiple roles, at least in English.  To me that looks like a miswritten attempt at the (clearly balanced) ``'Back "to 'school'"'``.  Brackets really are easier, as there are few ambiguities.

Answer (score -1):

A simple approaching way might be like this for only first braces:

```
function Search(str) {
    const onlyBrackets = str.replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g, "");
    const left = onlyBrackets.replace(/[)]/g, "");
    const right = onlyBrackets.replace(/[(]/g, "");

    str = left.length === right.length ? 1 : 0
    return str
}

console.log(Search("(coder)(byte))")) // 0

console.log(Search("(c(oder))b(yte)")) // 1
```

Comment: Does not deal with quotes, nor with multiple types of parentheses. Gives wrong result for `")("`.

Answer (score -2):

```
   function isParenthesisBalanced(_str) {
 var parenMap = {'{':'}', '[':']', '(':')'};
 var parenStack =[];

 for(var i=0;i<_str.length; i++) {
     if(_str[i] in parenMap) {
         parenStack.push(_str[i]);
     } else if(Object.values(parenMap).indexOf(_str[i]) != -1) {
        if(parenMap[parenStack.pop()] != _str[i]) return false;
     }
 }
 return true;
}
```

Comment: Does not deal with quotes.